# Error: unknown type name List when trying to create a Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

So I'm new to C and am trying to create my linked list. But for some reason I keep getting this `error: unknown type name List`. This is what I have so far:

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct List{
    struct Node *head;
};

void add(List *list, int value){
    if(list-> head == NULL){ 
        struct Node *newNode;
        newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        newNode->data = value;
        list->head = newNode;
    }

    else{
        struct Node *tNode = list->head;
        while(tNode->next != NULL){
            tNode = tNode->next;
        }
        struct Node *newNode;
        newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        newNode->data = value;

        tNode->next = newNode;
    }
}



void printNodes(struct List *list){
    struct Node *tNode = list->head;
    while(tNode != NULL){
        printf("Value of this node is:%d", tNode->data);
        tNode = tNode->next;
    }
}

 int main()
{
    struct List list = {0}; //Initialize to null
    add(&list, 200);
    add(&list, 349);
    add(&list, 256);
    add(&list, 989);
    printNodes(&list);
    return 0;
}
```

I am coming here for help as I don't know how to debug in C and having come from Java don't know too much about pointers, memory allocation and stuff and wonder if I might have messed up there somehow. I also get this warning further down and don't know what this might mean either.

warning: implicit declaration of function 'add' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anywhere a struct type is in use (assuming you're not using a `typedef`), you have to put the `struct` keyword before the type name.

So this:

```
void add(List *list, int value){
```

Should be:

```
void add(struct List *list, int value){
```

Comment: Great. That removed the error but now there's an issue with my printing of the nodes. Nothing prints out. I'll edit my question to include the printNodes function and how I'm using it. Am i missing something basic there as well?