# Unknown type name using struct in c

Tags: c

I get an error that tells me List is an unknown type name, i havent encountered this problem before please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>


struct listnode {
  int maxSizeOfList, indexOfLastItemOfList;
  float *array;
};


int createList(List *list, int size) {
  list-> maxSizeOfList = size; //initialization phase
  list->indexOfLastItemOfList = -1;
  array = malloc(sizeof(float) * size);
}


float addItem(float item, List l) {
  l.array[++l.indexOfLastItemOfList] = item; //addditem to the end of list
 }

float getItem(int index, List l) {
  return l.array[l.indexOfLastItemOfList]; //return the indexed item
}

int sizeOfList(List l) {
  return l.indexOfLastItemOfList+1; //simple return statement
}

void deleteList(List *) {
  free(l->arraay); //free up dyamic array memory
  list-> maxSizeOfList = 0 ; //initialization phase
  list->indexOfLastItemOfList = -1;
  array = NULL;  
}
```

Comment: There is no `List` type in C. Do you have a `typedef` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: unknown type name List when trying to create a Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504045/error-unknown-type-name-list-when-trying-to-create-a-linked-list)

Comment: do i need to add in typedef before struct?

Comment: Put `typedef struct listnode List;` after `struct listnode {...};`

Comment: yeah, or `typedef `  before and  ` List`  after.

Answer (score -1):

No  list data type in c. List is present as a data type in java.If you want to use performance like list type you need to create such user defined data type.